# How do I change my Google password?

Tags: google-account, passwords

My account was hacked I and need to reset my password.

What icon do I click? I can't see where it is written "change your Logon".

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security and then click "Change password".

If the hacker changed your password and you can't access it, try to recover your account from https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery